# ReactJS/Firebase : How do I let a user delete themselves?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

As per guidelines, we need to implement a feature that the user can effectively delete their account.

How do I allow the user to remove themselves (from Authentication)

I have tried:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#web-version-9_11

But all I get is deleteUser is not a function or similar.

They are currently logged into the app.

Comment: "But all I get is deleteUser is not a function or similar." Can you share your code so we can actually check what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.delete()
```